# Last name ordered wrongly in airticket

Tags: air-travel, tickets

My name is the airticket is ordered differently than the name in my passport.

example: 
First name : Emily
Last name :JaneDoe
But in my airticket it is 
First name: Emily Jane
Last name: Doe

I booked it through a travel agency and I was told my only option is to cancel the air ticket and book it again. 
Is there any other option??

Thank you

Comment: call the airlines. such minor mistakes can be corrected mostly without additional cost.

Comment: but call well before the day of your flight.

Answer (score 2):

There are three options:

- your travel agent is right,
- the airline corrects it at little or no cost
- the airline tells you it is alright as it is.

But to find out you need to call the airline. Go with what the airline tells you to do.
And better call sooner rather than later.

If it is the first, 'cancel and buy a new ticket' and the travel agent entered the information wrong, ask them to pay for the extra cost. (Likely they will not pay or at least not all but you do have a chance they will pay.)

Whatever you do, do not wait till the day of the flight as getting things corrected on short notice is harder and can be very costly.